# IOS JSON error when failing to connect

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad

http://imasters.com.br/artigo/22804/ios/trabalhando-com-json-em-aplicacoes-iphone follow this tutorial to read a `JSON` in my application, and works correctly except when there is not a connection to the internet .

If you have a failure during the process for applying it in time to read the `JSON`, sometimes when connected to `WIFI` iPhone takes a while to get `IP` if I access the application at this time also breaks the application.

How can I identify it to fix the error?

Comment: The mistake that hopefully fix is already posted in the question above, I want my application does not break when the User is no internet connection or the correct JSON not come as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to resolve this issue:

1: Put a check if the data is a valid JSON before you parse it.

2: Set a JSON at client end for handling Errors i.e. create a json when you receive error from network connection. & load that JSON to parse and return that JSON. So if you don't get Server response, You can give your JSON to parse.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Reacability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) class to make sure that you are able to connect to the website before making any requests for the JSON.

You could also use [AFJSONRequestOperation](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html) which is a part of [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) that is very good with error checking and won't parse invalid JSON.